# C: can a function return a global variable?

Tags: c, global-variables, return

Suppose a I have a *.c file with a global variable ("global" in the sense that it has file scope) and a function.  Can the function return that variable as a value to be used in other translation units?

I assume the answer is "yes."  If nothing else, I assume that in C return operates under "copy" semantics---the value of the return expression is returned.  But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. And you're correct: if you return something like an `int`, then you'll return a copy of its current. If you return a pointer, you'll give them access to the variable itself.

Answer (score 3):

Well,something like this?

**a.c**

```
int foo = 3;

int get_foo() { return foo; }
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#include "a.c"

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", get_foo());
    return 0;
}
```

output:

`3`

Answer (score 1):

> I assume the answer is "yes." If nothing else, I assume that in C
>   return operates under "copy" semantics---the value of the return
>   expression is returned. But I'm not sure.

You are correct.

> Suppose a I have a *.c file with a global variable ("global" in the
>   sense that it has file scope)

Keep in mind that declaring a variable globally in a .c file makes it global **period**.  If you want it restricted to file scope, use the `static` modifier.  You will still be able to pass the value out via a function.

Answer (score 1):

If I were pedantic I would say no.  It can return the *value* of a global variable.  That value will be an instantaneous copy, not a reference.  That is to say when the global changes, the value will not change.

Beyond that [for all sorts of reasons](http://www.eetimes.com/discussion/break-point/4025723/A-pox-on-globals) the global variable should be avoided in the first instance.

Comment: Yes, I'd like to avoid using a global variable, but I want to use the file tree walking function nftw, and I don't see a good way to pass my state information back and forth with that function.

Comment: Nothing about the nftw() interface suggests to me that a global variable is necessary.  Perhaps you should post a question about that, with code.

Comment: OK, I posted the question.  I didn't use any code; I think the description suffices.